# VueJS generate multiple web components

Tags: vue.js, web-component, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I'm currently using vue-cli-service to generate a web component like the following:

> vue-cli-service build --target wc --no-clean --name WidgetX ./src/widgets/WidgetX.vue --mode development (or test/staging/production)

Imagine I have multiple widgets inside the /widgets folder and I will need to generate separated web components for each, is it possible to do that automatically ? Or will I have to add this script to each one?

Also is it possible to trigger all these web components generation automatically after the build ?

> npm run build -- --mode development (or test/staging/production)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out a way to provide what I need at the moment:

**package.json**

```
"postbuild": "node scripts/web-components.js"
```

In this script i will iterate in every file under folder /src/widgets using `fs.readdirSync(widgetsFolder);` and execute the vue-cli-service build for web components.

For now after every build process it's triggering the generation of web components as needed.

Comment: Can you share. you `scripts/web-components.js` file?